# Code is not printing extracted names of sororities/fraternities from the site. No errors were given

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

Wrote some code for extracting the top 5 fraternities and sororities from the Greek Rank site. For some reason the output does not contain any of the desired elements extracted from the site.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://www.greekrank.com/uni/51/greek-life/"

page = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

cards = soup.find_all('div', class_='card-body')


print("Top 5 Fraternities/Sororities:")
print("-----------------------------------")
print("| Ranking | Fraternity/Sorority   |")
print("-----------------------------------")


for i, card in enumerate(cards):
    if i == 5:
        break
    ranking = card.find('h5', class_='card-title').text.strip()
    name = card.find('h6', class_='card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted').text.strip()
    print(f"| {ranking:<8} | {name:<23} |")
print("-----------------------------------")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Class names have changed I guess. Here's my attempt at it:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://www.greekrank.com/uni/51/greek-life/"

page = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

all_frats = soup.find('div', class_='fraternity-rankings')
frats = all_frats.findChildren('div',class_='row')


print("Top 5 Fraternities/Sororities:")
print("-----------------------------------")
print("| Ranking | Fraternity/Sorority   |")
print("-----------------------------------")


for i, frat in enumerate(frats):
    if i == 5:
        break
    cells=frat.findChildren('div',class_='cell')

    ranking = cells[4].text.strip().split()[1]
    name = cells[2].find('a').text.strip()
    print(f"| {ranking:<8} | {name:<23} |")
print("-----------------------------------")
```